# Java maximum literal number in eclipse

Tags: java

I have a line that looks like

```
if(numb2 < 10000000000000 & numb2 > 100000000000){
```

So in Eclipse it says 10000000000000 and 100000000000 are both out of the integer literal range. Specifically

The literal 10000000000000 of type int is out of range
and
The literal 1000000000000 of type int is out of range

I changed the line so it looked like

```
if(numb2 < 1000000000*10000 & numb2 > 100000000*1000){
```

but if you typed a number in that range it just said

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5555555555555"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at twothousandthirteen.LuckyNumber.main(LuckyNumber.java:12)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to extend the literal number range or do anything to fix the problem.

Thanks
KMehta

Comment: You can use `long` or `BigInteger` depending on your needs.

Comment: Have a look at `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: By the way, the & operator is not a logical AND - it's a bitwise AND, probably not what you want.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev actually you are incorrect. `&` is both a bitwuse AND *and* a logical AND when used with two booleans. The difference between `&` and `&&` is that `&` will always evaluate both sides, whereas `&&` will only evaluate the right side if the left side is `true` (known as "short cutting").

Comment: Even so, non-short-circuiting AND is uncalled for here. Won't hurt though.

Answer (score 4):

Those numbers are larger than the largest `int` value, which is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or 2147483647, and which is available as the constant [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

The reason you were able to code it as `1000000000*10000` is because although each multiplicand is within the range of the maximum `int` value, the result is not and java handles this by [overflowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow) the result so it falls within the valid range.

To fix the problem, make your variables `long` (64 bits) and your constants long also by appending `L` at the end if the number (the default numerical type in java is `int`), and your should use [`Long.parseLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) to cater for the larger values in your input.

Note that, like `int`, the range of `long` is limited too: to 2<sup>63</sup>-1 or 9223372036854775807, which is available as the constant [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE).

For arbitrarily large numbers, use the `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a `long` literal:

```
if(numb2 < 10000000000000L && numb2 > 100000000000L){
```

... and Long.parseLong to parse integers outside the `int` range, which is between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

```
Long.parseLong(input)
```

Of course, both literals are intended to be well above the `int` range, so if `numb2` is an `int`, then there's no point in testing that range.

Also, for boolean and, don't use `&`, use `&&`.  `&` is the bitwise-and operator and most certainly not what you're trying to do; `&&` is the logical "and".

Answer (score 0):

To learn the ranges of primitive values in Java, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

They are also available as static variables from the corresponding wrapper classes.  For example, [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: The answer will be indeed a merge of rgettman's answer and yours.

Answer (score 0):

What's the datatype of `numb2`? Is it `int`? If so, you don't need to check - `int` is not capable of storing numbers more that ~2,000,000,000 anyway. The condition is always true.

If it's `long`, on the other hand, all you need a `long` literal. That would go like this:

```
if(numb2 < 10000000000000L & numb2 > 100000000000L){
```

Comment: Here at SO, we say thanks by upvoting and/or accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numbers out of the range of int, you will have to use a different type. Integer values in eclipse only go up to 2^31-1 (signed). If you want to use a larger value, longs can go up to 2^63-1.

If you need a number even larger than that, a double can get very large but with very bad accuracy, so should not be used if you need accuracy. Another way for huge values is to use the [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, but that will create objects which may be difficult to deal with.